# How to make dynamic non-repeatable select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have try to create Dynamic Input group

**My expected is**

> dynamic selection box[length in config `var parameter`] with...
>
> 1. Non-duplicate `select option` --> I check when **click ,remove and append**
> 2. Can click to **add/remove** input group
> 3. limited by `var parameter`

So now **My actual result is**

> 1. not hide **will be select** option in new `select` of previous `select` on append
> 2. delete select **can't check** the repeating after remove
>
>    ---
>
> **But** After i **click** some where will back to normal as i expect **a little** because item what i click still no update

So here for long code
Thank for viewing

```js
var parameter =[
     "A"
    ,"B"
    ,"C"
    ,"D"            
];
$(document).ready(function(e){
    
    $('div.multiselect').append('<div class="selectlist"></div>');
    $('div.multiselect').append('<button class="btn btn-outline-light addlist">add search parameter</button>');
    $('div.multiselect').append('<button class="btn btn-success search">search</button>');
    addSelect();//Create first
    $('div.multiselect .addlist').click(function(){
        addSelect();
        
    });
    
});

(function($) {

        var origAppend = $.fn.append;

        $.fn.append = function () {
            return origAppend.apply(this, arguments).trigger("append");
        };
    })(jQuery);
    
    
var selectblock = function (){
    var outside = $(document.createElement("div")).addClass('input-group');
    var inside = $(document.createElement("select")).addClass('custom-select').on("click append",checkRepeat);
    
    var selVal=[];
    $("div.multiselect .selectlist div.input-group").each(function(){
        selVal.push($(this).find("select").val());
    });
    if(selVal.length == parameter.length){
        alert("Can't add more parameter");
        return;
    }
    for (var i =0 ; i < parameter.length ; i++){
        var option = $(document.createElement("option")).val(parameter[i]).text(parameter[i]);
        if($.inArray(parameter[i], selVal) > -1){
            option.attr("disabled","disabled").hide();
        }
        inside.append(option);
    }
    
    outside.append(inside);
    outside.append($(document.createElement("input")).attr('Type','Text').addClass('form-control'));
    var delbtn = $(document.createElement("button")).text("X").addClass('btn btn-danger input-group-append dellist');
    delbtn.click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
        checkRepeat;
    });
    outside.append(delbtn);
    
    
    return outside;
};

function addSelect(){
    $('div.multiselect .selectlist').append(selectblock);
    checkRepeat;
}

var checkRepeat = function (){
    //console.log('trigger');
    var selVal=[];
    $("div.multiselect .selectlist div.input-group").each(function(){
        selVal.push($(this).find("select").val());
    });

    $(this).parent().siblings("div.multiselect .selectlist div.input-group").find("select").find("option").removeAttr("disabled").show().filter(function(){
       var a=$(this).parent("select").val();
       return (($.inArray(this.value, selVal) > -1) && (this.value!=a));
    }).attr("disabled","disabled").hide();
    
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multiselect">
```

Comment: **Update:** I have sensed about `var checkRepeat` may be made troubles.